# Why does apache keep running out of memory?

Tags: server, apache2, memory, memory-usage

All the time my apache2 runs out of memory, I have 6 sites running on it.

My server specs are:

2 gig ram, 6 core processor, 60 gb hard drive, and a 1000 mb/s how can I sort the problem out? it crashes the whole server :(

[Screenshot:](http://phota.me/IbMf)
[image: screenshot showing apache's out of memory errors]

Answer (score 1):

This is not to do with Apache, but is to do with the sites you are running from it.

Either you have a memory leak in the software you are running, or you are a victim of your own success and are attracting too many concurrent visitors for the server resources you have.

So the possible avenues of attack are :

- Test for memory leaks

  - Repeated requests should not lead to slowly increasing memory consumption
- Limit the number of concurrent sessions by reconfiguring your app / web server
- Increase the amount of RAM in your server